# Is there a better way to pull in custom content without querying posts?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, templates, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom page template that pulls in media files via advanced custom fields, as well as query posts. Now, the client wants there to be three sections by default... each one populating with the appropriate images based on another advanced custom field for an image category (which I created).

Normally, I would just query_posts three times. Undoubtedly, this is a hack. Normally, it doesn't cause speed issues, however this site has roughly 50k images, and I'm afraid it will cause the load times to significantly decrease.

Is there a better way to do this way to do this? Maybe pull in all images and then sort them based on the category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a hack, this is what databases are designed for- querying large quantities of data. If you're concerned about load, you should employ [caching](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/Caching) on data that doesn't change frequently.

That said, you should not be using `query_posts` to create additional queries. Really, [you shouldn't be using query_posts at all](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats). Create additional queries via [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: actually, the pre_get_posts action is the best option :) query_posts and WP_Query are just more convenient

Comment: @KeganQuimby `pre_get_posts` is typically for altering just the main query, `WP_Query` is for additional loops. `query_posts` just calls `WP_Query` itself, but it overwrites global variables and produces unpredictable results with things like conditional tags and should be avoided entirely.